Custom ILogger implementation best practice when an exception occurs
Trawling through some code today and came across a custom ILogger implementation that writes directly to SQL Server.
Aside from the fact it's not using an in-memory queue, it appears to have no logic around exception handling.
It then made me ask myself what is best practice here?
If for instance a SQL exception were thrown, should this continue up?
Could this then cause a continued chain of events (i.e. logging this failure with the same logger, that would subsequently fail).
Should it be caught silently with a documented approach to ensure another logger (e.g. Windows Event Log) is configured as a backup?
Have tried searching for this myself but haven't had much luck beyond basic implementation.

a custom ILogger implementation that writes directly to SQL Server -> do you mean you are trying to design a custom log provider which is used to write to database directly? If so, please allow me to share some of my ideas. Firstly, I think log provider should play the role that no matter what exception throws, no matter the exception is thrown from database or the log provider itself, the log provider should always write the log somewhere, database first, if failed then maybe chain multiple providers and write to local file system or event viewer(windows machine).

Therefore, I agree with you that when a SQL exception was thrown, for example a connectivity issue, logger should retry to log that failure or try to write to somewhere else.
